# Error: An unexpected error occurred while trying to open file C:\mypath\venv\Lib\site-packages\tabula\tabula-1.0.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Tags: tabula

I'm sorry for asking, but I can't find why I'm getting this errors. My code:

```
import tabula
import pandas as pd
from tabula.io import read_pdf
pdf_in = 'C://Users//Кирилл//Desktop//1//122.pdf'
PDF = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_in, pages='all', multiple_tables=True)



pdf_out_csv = "C://Users//Кирилл//Desktop//1//15.csv"



tabula.convert_into (pdf_in, pdf_out_csv, pages='all')
```

The erros to be exact are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Кирилл\Desktop\python\test 3.py", line 5, in <module>
    PDF = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_in, pages='all', multiple_tables=True)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Кирилл\PycharmProjects\label\venv\Lib\site-packages\tabula\io.py", line 425, in read_pdf
    output = _run(java_options, tabula_options, path, encoding)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Кирилл\PycharmProjects\label\venv\Lib\site-packages\tabula\io.py", line 88, in _run
    result = subprocess.run(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Кирилл\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 571, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['java', '-Dfile.encoding=UTF8', '-jar', 'C:\\Users\\Кирилл\\PycharmProjects\\label\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\tabula\\tabula-1.0.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar', '--pages', 'all', '--guess', '--format', 'JSON', 'C://Users//Кирилл//Desktop//1//122.pdf']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

reinstalled tabula-py library, reinstalled java